# Find related bought products (in a SQL Server database)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to tables, `Bills` and `BillDetails`.

The `Bill` table contains the following columns:

```
billId, salesManId, purchaseBranch
```

The `BillDetails` table contains these columns:

```
billDetailId , billId, productId,  purchaseBranch, Quantity
```

What I want is report to find top 2 related products

For example

1. People who bought iPhone X also bought

   - Nomad Rugged Cable
   - Kenu Stance Tripod
2. People who bought Samsung s5282 also bought:

   - Bluetooth Keyboards
   - MP3 Player

I know it is somewhat called recommendation system but I can not figure out how to implement it

Comment: And what is a "person" in your tables?  Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Comment: Also when you say "top 2" related products, how would you define "top"? The most frequently bought by the same user? The most expensive? The cheapest? The most popular bought by all users?

Comment: @DavidG The most popular bought by all users

Answer (score 1):

If the purchases are on the same bill, you can use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select bd1.productid, bd2.productid, count(*)
from billdetails bd1 join
     billdetails bd2
     on bd1.billid = bd2.billid
group by bd1.productid, bd2.productid
order by bd1.productid, count(*) desc;
```

For each product, this gives all related products, ordered by the frequency of appearance together on a bill.

Comment: what do you mean by that If the purchases are on the same bill?

if you mean bill contains more than one product then yes 
for example bill 1 may contain product x and product y
bill2 may contain product x and product z 
bill3 may contain product x and product y

then product x and product y is the most products bought together